# UnsafePointer<DSPComplex> in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

The code:

```
vDSP_ctoz(UnsafePointer<DSPComplex>(stream), 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSizePOT / 2))
```

used to work fine in Swift 2.3. Now I get the error:
'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_) to temporarly view memory...

"stream" is a parameter from the function as:

```
func FFT(stream : UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, size: UInt)
```

I guess the error message might be misleading. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please show how you declared `stream`. The right solution depends on in.

Comment: @OOper I re-edited the question. 'stream' is a function parameter of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need a basic **UnsafePointer conversion**.

[SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)

> #### UnsafePointer conversion
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<Pointee> {
>   func withMemoryRebound<T>(to: T.Type, capacity count: Int,
>     _ body: (Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<T>) throws -> ()) rethrows
> }
> ```

Generally, when you want to convert `aPointer` of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` to `anotherPointer` of `UnsafeMutablePointer<U>`, you need to write something like this:

```
aPointer.withMemoryRebound(to: U.self, capacity: capacity) { //<- You need `capacity` counted in `U`
    anotherPointer in //<-this becomes `UnsafeMutablePointer<U>`
    //...use `anotherPointer` inside the closure
    //...
    //Do NOT take `anotherPointer` out of this closure
}
```

In your case, you can write something like this:

(Assuming `bufferSizePOT` is `Int`.)

```
stream.withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: bufferSizePOT / 2) {dspComplexStream in
    vDSP_ctoz(dspComplexStream, 2, &output, 1, UInt(bufferSizePOT / 2))
}
```